# why the shell outputs infinite similar messages when I install cmake

Tags: c++, shell, ubuntu, installation, cmake

I try to install cmake by the source distribution on the ubuntu22.04. I download the source distribution in web and then

```
❯ tar -zxv -f cmake-3.27.7.tar.gz
❯ cd cmake-3.27.7 
❯ ./bootstrap
```

but it outputs

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.27.7, Copyright 2000-2023 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc   
C++ compiler on this system is: g++    
Makefile processor on this system is: gmake
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
```

and

```
g++     -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -DCMAKE_BOOTSTRAP    -DCMake_HAVE_CXX_MAKE_UNIQUE=1 -DCMake_HAVE_CXX_FILESYSTEM=1   -I/home/euler/Downloads/cmake-3.27.7/Bootstrap.cmk   -I/home/euler/Downloads/cmake-3.27.7/Source   -I/home/euler/Downloads/cmake-3.27.7/Source/LexerParser   -I/home/euler/Downloads/cmake-3.27.7/Utilities/std   -I/home/euler/Downloads/cmake-3.27.7/Utilities  -c /home/euler/Downloads/cmake-3.27.7/Source/cmDependsC.cxx -o cmDependsC.o
```

the last code block or some similar with that constantly outputs. I don't know what had happened. Waiting half minute, I have to type `cltr+c` to stop it.
when I type `make`, it can't find makefile.

I searched for the problem in google but didn't find similar one either by chinese or english, and asked help for chatGPT but it didn't work. I know there are other way to install acmake, but I want to figure out it.

Comment: "the last code block or some **similar** with that constantly outputs" - So it compiles many source files, one by one. If you look into [Source/](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/v3.27.7/Source) subdirectory, you may find many source files, all of them needs to be compiled for make a program.

Comment: Just give it more time.

Comment: Seven years ago, my project took 4 hours to compile.  Thanks to faster hardware, these days it only takes 25 minutes to compile.

Comment: As above, Just confirm that the last 4 columns are changing (really the last 2 is all you need), i.e. `-o cmDependsC.o` shows the current filename that is being creating. Salute for compiling your own!

Comment: thanks for your kind comments. It is my impatientence that leads to my confusion